# Understanding Different Location Icons in iOS App Background Usage

Tags: ios, core-location, background-task, ios-statusbar

My iOS app uses user **location in background**. I usually see 3 types of location icon shown in the status bar for my app using Location background.

**1.** An outlined hollowed arrow.
**2.** A location icon of white arrow with blue rounded background.
**3.** A location icon of white arrow with a blue rectangle background shows up.

My question under which conditions the different types of icons are shown? And if there is any other type of icon appears what are they and situations for appearing those icons accordingly.

[image]

I have never seen the 3rd type for google map or apple maps in my iPhone. But is appearing for my app. So, is there any way to shop showing this location icon(3rd type) for my app?